# How come the publish_action is so unstable?

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

Below you can find the code I use, as you can see it has been copied from the sample code. However the result is very unstable, more than often it returns 'unexpected error please try again later', also the dev app has some problems. At random it clears the app namespace, while I did not delete it. In fact, the app namespace is still active so if I re-enter my app namespace it says it already exists.

This has kept me busy for 12 hours now. I was wondering if other people are experiencing the same problem that it might be a bug on the Facebook part.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# mycookieapp: 
                  http://ogp.me/ns/apps/mycookieapp#">
  <title>OG Tutorial App</title>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="115973895205576" /> 
  <meta property="og:type" content="mycookieapp:recipe" /> 
  <meta property="og:title" content="Stuffed Cookies" /> 
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.jpg" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="The Turducken of Cookies" /> 
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.crystalminds.nl/facebook/index.html">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function postCook()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/mycookieapp:cook?recipe=http://www.crystalminds.nl/facebook/index.html',
        'post',
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured: ' + response.error.message);
           } else {
              alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        });
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '115973895205576', // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
          });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=115973895205576";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

  <h3>Stuffed Cookiess</h3>
  <p>
    <img title="Stuffed Cookies" 
         src="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.jpg" 
         width="550"/>
  </p>

  <br>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Cook" onclick="postCook()" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's at least one open bug in Facebook's bug tracker about the app namespace saving issue; as such i think this question is too localised, and won't be of use to anyone once those bugs are resolved

Comment: Is there anywhere I can check the bug tracker?

Comment: Right now the homepage of the bug tracker (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) shows me two bugs about namespace failing to save, i presume they'll be de-duped and processed shortly